# What is the mechanism of "torch.Tensor in torch.Tensor" in python and why is there such a confusing phenomenon?

Tags: python, pytorch, conditional-statements

**environment:**

google colab

Python 3.7.11

torch 1.9.0+cu102

**code and output**

```
import torch
b = torch.tensor([[1,1,1],[4,5,6]])
print(b.T)

print(torch.tensor([1,4]) in b.T) # 
print(torch.tensor([2,1]) in b.T) #
print(torch.tensor([1,2]) in b.T) # Not as expected
print(torch.tensor([2,5]) in b.T) # Not as expected

----------------------------------------------------------
tensor([[1, 4],
        [1, 5],
        [1, 6]])
True
False
True
True
```

**probleam**

I want to judge whether one tensor is in another.But the result above is confusing.

What is the mechanism of `in`? How should I use it to avoid the above unexpected output?

And is it the problem of `torch.tensor.T`? (When `.T` is not used and initial `b = torch.tensor([[1,4],[1,5],[1,6]])`, there also can be no expected output)

Comment: That's great, thanks for taking the time to provide an edit to add the source code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/82123758ba6bc96bb33687bf8474f03006b4d42c/torch/_tensor.py#L710) is as follows (edit: source code snippet found by [@Rune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15548268/rune)):

```
def __contains__(self, element):
    r"""Check if `element` is present in tensor
    Args:
        element (Tensor or scalar): element to be checked
            for presence in current tensor"
    """
    if has_torch_function_unary(self):
        return handle_torch_function(Tensor.__contains__, (self,), self, element)
    if isinstance(element, (torch.Tensor, Number)):
        # type hint doesn't understand the __contains__ result array
        return (element == self).any().item()  # type: ignore[union-attr]

    raise RuntimeError(
        "Tensor.__contains__ only supports Tensor or scalar, but you passed in a %s." %
        type(element)
    )
```

The [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) (used by the '`in`' syntax: `x in b`) operator is equivalent to applying [`torch.any`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.any.html) on the `x == b` boolean condition:

```
>>> b = tensor([[1, 1, 1],
                [4, 5, 6]])

>>> check_in = lambda x: torch.any(x == b.T)
```

Then

```
>>> check_in(torch.tensor([1,4]))
tensor(True)

>>> check_in(torch.tensor([2,1]))
tensor(False)

>>> check_in(torch.tensor([1,2]))
tensor(True)

>>> check_in(torch.tensor([2,5]))
tensor(True)
```

It is the position of the elements in the columns that matters not the exact match of the whole column.

---

`.T` reverses the order of the dimension: equivalent to `b.permute(1, 0)` and has no effect on the results. The only constraint you have when using `in` is `x`'s size needs to match the shape of `b[1]`. *If you're working with `b.T` then it will be `b[0]`*.

```
>>> check_in = lambda x: torch.any(x == b)

>>> check_in(torch.tensor([1,1,1]))
tensor(True)

>>> check_in(torch.tensor([5,4,2]))
tensor(False)
```